# Melt data from binary columns

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), google = c(1,1), amazon = c(0,1))
```

How is it possible to melt columns checking in all columns except from id if there is 1 and create a new row into a new dataframe using the id and the column name. Example output:

```
data.frame <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2), name = c("google", "google", "amazon")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pivoting to 'long' format use `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dframe %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  filter(as.logical(value)) %>% 
  select(-value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id name  
  <dbl> <chr> 
1     1 google
2     2 google
3     2 amazon
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `melt` + `subset`

```
> subset(melt(setDT(dframe), id.var = "id"), !!value, select = -value)
   id variable
1:  1   google
2:  2   google
3:  2   amazon
```